# Perl Use Variable declared in 'new'

Tags: perl, variables

If in a Perl module I have a 'new' function that declares:

```
 my $self = $class->SUPER::new($pArgsProcessor, $pResponse, kStrFormatHtml);
 $self->{mStrRunType} = $pArgsProcessor->readQueryString('runType');
 $self->{mStrStartDate} = $pArgsProcessor->readQueryString('startdate');
 $self->{mStrEndDate} = $pArgsProcessor->readQueryString('enddate');
 bless $self, $class;
 return $self;
```

Is there a way to use the data stored in '$self' in another function? I'm trying to use 'mStrRunType'

Comment: `bless $self, $class;` shouldn't be necessary. The superclass should already have blessed it correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$self` is probably an object, and all the subs in your package can be called as methods. Then:

```
my $object = Your::Class->new(...);

$object->foo(42);
```

Inside the `foo` method, the object will be the first argument:

```
sub foo {
  my ($self, $meaning_of_life) = @_;
  say "mStrEndDate = $self->{mStrEndDate}";
  ...;
}
```

Notes:

- You should not generally rebless the `$self` in your constructor. If the superclasses are written to support inheritance, then `$class->SUPER::new(...)` ensures that the reference is blessed into the correct `$class`.
- You naming scheme suggests you might want to use a more complex data structure:

  ```
  $self->{mStr} = {
    RunType   => ...,
    StartDate => ...,
    EndDate   => ...,
  };
  ```

Comment: +1, though I think the naming scheme might just be a heavy accent retained from another programming language/convention:  "m" for member (as opposed to class) variables, and "Str" for string variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor looks correct. Assuming that your constructor is similar to this:

```
sub new {
   my $class = shift;
   my $pArgsProcessor, $pResponse, kStrFormatHtml; #shift your constructor params..

   my $self = $class->SUPER::new($pArgsProcessor, $pResponse, kStrFormatHtml);
   $self->{mStrRunType} = $pArgsProcessor->readQueryString('runType');
   $self->{mStrStartDate} = $pArgsProcessor->readQueryString('startdate');
   $self->{mStrEndDate} = $pArgsProcessor->readQueryString('enddate');

   bless $self, $class;
   return $self;
}
```

Then your method should be able to use your parameters:

```
sub test {
   my $self = shift;

   if (defined $self->{mStrEndDate}) {
       print $self->{mStrEndDate};
   } else {
       print "not defined?";
   }
}
```

If your keys are still undefined then make sure that $pArgsProcessor methods are returning defined values.